# Navigation bar items' position remains same if image size of an item is more than default navigation bar height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add an image icon( whose height is greater than default height of navigation bar ) into my navigation bar. But when I add it, the navigation bar height increases but the position of other items remains same i.e. they are not center aligned vertically.You can see how it looks like  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwl8f.png). 
Below is my html file :-

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Search database</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/bookurbus-small.png"/></a> 
      </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Buses <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
         </ul>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search on Google" name="q" size="31" value="">
       </div>
   </form>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Manage Bookings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Help Me</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

The problem gets solved if i use this :-

```
    <style>
        .nav, .navbar-form{
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
        }
    </style>
```

Is there any other better method through which i can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo img
{
 height:100%;
}
.navbar-brand
{
padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Search database</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body> 
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header ">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand logo"><img src="https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/02/Olympic-logo.png"/></a> 
      </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Buses <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hotels <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
         </ul>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search">
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search on Google" name="q" size="31" value="">
       </div>
   </form>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Manage Bookings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Help Me</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </nav>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use line height for the navbar links.

```
.navbar-nav li a {
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/nD4tW/412/)